# DDR3 logic levels - AC or DC?

Tags: memory, signal-integrity, ddr, ddr3

In a DDR3 datasheet, I found different voltage levels (AC and DC.) I already know about DC logic levels but I don't know about AC logic levels.

What is the difference between the two?

Do the AC values corresponds to the acceptable noise levels on the signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means that the "DC levels" are the actual nominal DC levels the voltage stabilizes after transients from a change have decayed away, but the "AC levels" are the larger allowed undershoot or overshoot levels during a transient before stabilizing to the DC levels.